# Unable to read CSV file via Pandas in Flask app in Python Anywhere

Tags: python, csv, flask, web-applications

I'm trying to display the first five rows of a `CSV` file in an HTML page using flask app in python anywhere. I'm new to coding and I can't figure out what's the mistake. I have uploaded the `CSV` file in the working directory, created a 'templates' folder in "my site" directory and uploaded the example.html file in it.

This is the code in flask_app.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/example')
def dataframe():
    df = pd.read_csv("movies_metadata.csv")
    return render_template("example.html",  data=df.head(5).to_html())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

This is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>DataFrame Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Titanic DataFrame</h1> 
 
{{data | safe}}
 
</body>
</html>
```

I want the first five rows of the `CSV` file to be displayed in the HTML page.

Comment: Your code works for me. Can you add the error message you're getting? I suspect the file is called `movie_metadata.csv` (singular movie) and it's just a typo leading to FileNotFoundError.

Comment: The error is "The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again." Also, the CSV file name is correct its plural. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget adding `example`? `http://localhost:5000/example` or `http://127.0.0.1:5000/example` should work. Flask outputs the base URL on startup, such as `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)`

Comment: I double checked that I have added the example.html file in the 'templates' folder. Also, 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/example' this link is not working. It says 'This site can't be reached'. Sorry for bothering you!

Comment: How do you start the Flask app? Do you get the `Running on...` message ?

Comment: I headed to the 'Web' menu in the pythonanywhere.com and clicked on myname.pythonanywhere.com. Before this I tried a simple flask app which displays 'hello world' and it worked.

Comment: Ah, I missed you were using this service. Have you read their [docs about Flask](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/) ?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will look into the documentation and update the comment if it works.